# CakePHP 3 - Strange behavior $this->set(); affected after setting

Tags: php, cakephp, view, timestamp, entity

Today I've found myself a strange behavior in CakePHP.

What I wanted to archive was updating an column in the database to reflect the last viewed date. This could be done with 'touch()' when using a different column then the standard timestamp events (like created, modified, etc).

- What I want: I want to show the previous 'last-viewed' date on the
  page.
- What happends: The current date timestamp is being showed on
  the page.

The strange behavior I'm seeing here is this: after I set my entity to the view variable and update touch the 'last-viewed' date, the data in the setted view variable reflects this change.

Code of setting the entity to the view:

```
// get the request entity with the ID:
$request = $this->Requests->get($request_id);

// set the entity to the $request view variable:
$this->set('request', $request);

// finally update the last viewed date (database column name: 'opened'):
$this->Requests->touch($request, 'Requests.opened');
$this->Requests->save($request);
```

Why is the $request view variable reflecting the change of the touch which is executed after setting the variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

> As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as
>   value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows
>   object accessors to find the actual object

to achieve what you want you should do

```
// set the entity to the $request view variable:
$this->set('request', clone $request);
```

but maybe consider passing to the view just the previous 'last-viewed' date and not the whole cloned entity

Comment: I will need the whole request Entity, so this should theoretically be fine. I'm going to test it now, thanks for your response :) - Your answer seems to work! thanks a lot.